# Spawn number with animation ontop of element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make the effect you probably know of video games when yours score increases. I want to have a number and if a user scores, a second number just above the score number spawns and slowly moves up and fade away.

I think the animations can be made with jquery but how can I spawn a number/element at the same spot where the score element is?

Example code:

```html
    <span id="score">50</span>
```

```js
    AddScoreAnimation() {
        var element = $('<span/>')//How can I set it in the right position where #score is?
        $(element).text('+20');
        $(element).animate({
          top: '-=120',
          opacity: 0.0
        }, 1000);
        $('#score').text(70);
    }
```

Comment: Do not forget to accept my answer and upvote If I have helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CSS animation and pseudo-selectors with a bit of javascript. No need to include jQuery for this :)

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const score = document.querySelector('.score');
let count = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  setScore(20)
});


function setScore(value) {
  score.dataset.added = '+' + value;
  score.dataset.total = count += value;
  if (count) score.classList.add('animate');

  setTimeout(() => {
    score.classList.remove('animate');
  }, 500)
}


setScore(0)
```

```css
.score {
  position: relative;
  padding: .5rem;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

/*
   pseudo elements used to display 
   the data attribute values
*/
.score::before,
.score::after {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* total score */
.score::before {
  content: attr(data-total);
}

/* added score */
.score::after {
  content: attr(data-added);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* 
    position added score above total
    0% will make it overlay the total 
  */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

/* total score animation (fade in) */
.score.animate::before {
  animation: fade-in .5s;
}
@keyframes fade-in-scale {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* added score animation (fade in up) */
.score.animate::after {
  animation: fade-in-up .5s;
}
@keyframes fade-in-up {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  50%  { opacity: 1; }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}




body {
  padding: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="score" data-added="0" data-total="0">
</div>
<button>+20</button>
```

Comment: Is `count` needed for this? Isn't it possible to just use `score.dataset.total += value` ?

Comment: @sirzento Its good to check whether there is value via `if count` otherwise do not show any animation. Its a good practice thats why he added that :)

Comment: The count check also prevents animation when initialized (using setScore(0)).

Zero is treated as a falsy value in js – why the animate class will not be added.

Answer (score 1):

Recreated your example using `fadeIn` `fadeOut` which is much simpler and easy does the same job as you wanted intead of using .animate.

I have also used some `setTimeout` to show the user that +20 is getting added and then showing final score.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
function AddScoreAnimation(value) {

  var _this = $('#score')
  var currValue = _this.text()
  var incValue = parseInt(currValue) + parseInt(value)

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(_this).fadeOut(500).text('+' + value).fadeIn(500);
  }, 700)
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(_this).fadeOut(500).text(incValue).fadeIn(500);
  }, 2000)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="score">50</span>

<br>
<button id="add" value="20" onclick="AddScoreAnimation(this.value)">
Add +20
</button>
```